# The transaction cannot succeed due to error: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: uniswap, transferfrom

I am having errors whenever I try to call add liquidity from my contract.
Error: The transaction cannot succeed due to the error: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED.
I have almost approved each and every address.

Link: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x7cab26e8b57025434c66778836c1d5cc4e7049373e74c550152f1184f908627c

```
function addLiquidityFromContract(
    address tokenA,
    address tokenB,
    uint256 amountADesired,
    uint256 amountBDesired,
    uint256 amountAMin,
    uint256 amountBMin,
    address to,
    uint256 deadline ) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    IERC20 tokenAddressA = IERC20(tokenA);
    IERC20 tokenAddressB = IERC20(tokenB);
    // create the pair if it doesn't exist yet
    if (IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(tokenA, tokenB) == address(0)) {
        IUniswapV2Factory(factory).createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
    }
    tokenAddressA.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountADesired);
    tokenAddressB.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountBDesired);
    address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(tokenA, tokenB);
    tokenAddressA.approve(pair, IERC20(tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
    tokenAddressB.approve(pair, IERC20(tokenB).balanceOf(address(this)));        
    tokenAddressA.approve(address(this), IERC20(tokenA).balanceOf(msg.sender));
    tokenAddressB.approve(address(this), IERC20(tokenB).balanceOf(msg.sender));
    tokenAddressA.approve(liquidityAddress, IERC20(tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
    tokenAddressB.approve(liquidityAddress, IERC20(tokenB).balanceOf(address(this)));
    IUniswapV2Router01 addLiq = IUniswapV2Router01(liquidityAddress);
    (amountA, amountB, liquidityAB) = addLiq.addLiquidity(
        tokenA,
        tokenB,
        amountADesired,
        amountBDesired,
        amountAMin,
        amountBMin,
        to,
        deadline
    );
    emit details(amountA, amountB, liquidityAB);
    return true; }
```

why am I getting this error and how to resolve it?
please do help

Comment: You're supposed to approve UniswapV2Router, not the pair address

Comment: @Foxxxey I have done that too. it is liquidity address

Comment: Did you try pasting a failed transaction ID in dashboard.tenderly.co/ to see exactly where it reverts?